# Can one say the name of Hashem in a song

Tags: halacha

If one holds that we say Hashems name while saying a praise like in shabbat zemirot how does that appky to an Isreali song where some singers say The Name outright? If the song is meant for a praise does that fall under the same category as zemirot?

Comment: Rabbi Zev Smith
Challenging Shem Hashem Questions

TorahAnytime Links
  Video https://MyTAT.me/v253206
 Audio https://MyTAT.me/a253206

Comment: Are you talking about Elokim? Some say that isn’ta main name, I believe